# Round A APAC Test 2016 Country Leader

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying Google APAC [Question](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/11274486/dashboard) for practice, but the submission says my solution is incorrect.

> The Constitution of a certain country states that the leader is the
>   person with the name containing the greatest number of different
>   alphabet letters. (The country uses the uppercase English alphabet
>   from A through Z.) For example, the name GOOGLE has four different
>   alphabet letters: E, G, L, and O. The name APAC CODE JAM has eight
>   different letters. If the country only consists of these 2 persons,
>   APAC CODE JAM would be the leader.
>
> If there is a tie, the person whose name comes earliest in
>   alphabetical order is the leader.
>
> Given a list of names of the citizens of the country, can you
>   determine who the leader is?

I am unable to see why my submission results in an incorrect answer. Can you kindly point out where I've made mistakes?

I would also appreciate any feedback on improving my solution.

Many thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CountryLeader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
        int t = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        for (int i = 1; i <= t; ++i) {
            int n = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();
            List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                names.add(in.nextLine());
            }
//            System.out.println(names);
            System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": " + findLeader(names));
        }

    }

    public static String findLeader(List<String> names) {     
        String leader = "";
        int maxCount = 0;

        for (String name : names) {
            String current = name.replaceAll(" ","");;
            char[] charArr = current.toCharArray();
            int counter = 0;
            Map<Character, Boolean> charMap = new HashMap<Character, Boolean>();

            for (Character ch : charArr) {
                if (charMap.containsKey(ch))  {
                   continue; 
                } else {
                    charMap.put(ch, true);
                    counter++; 
                }
            }

            if (maxCount < counter) {
                leader = name;
                maxCount = counter;
            }
        }

        return leader;
    }
}
```

These are the tests I've tried and it seems like it is working fine:

```
3
3
ADAM
BOB
JOHNSON
2
A AB C
DEF
8
ABC DE
A B C D E F G
AB
A
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKCCCCCCCCc
ABCDEFGHIJKLM
CDEFGHIJKLMNO
```

Output:

```
Case #1: JOHNSON
Case #2: A AB C
Case #3: ABCDEFGHIJKLM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to check for alphabetical order, if two strings contain the same number of distinct characters. This can be corrected fairly easy, by adding an additional `if`-clause in `findLeader`:

```
if (maxCount < counter) {
    leader = name;
    maxCount = counter;
} else if(maxCount == counter && name.compareTo(leader) < 0) {
    // same number of distinct character => lexicographical ordering
    leader = name;
    maxCount = counter;
}
```